# Raw file to image

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

I have a file that is obtained from X-Ray machine , the extension of the file is .raw.
What I need is to  display this file in a picture box , How can be done in c# ?

Note : 
I have tried to convert it to byte array than to load it , the image is shown but corrupted.
I tried Image.FromFile() , error of (Out of memory) is thrown .
I tried to load from a stream and also an error occured (Paramater not valid).

Comment: Find the documentation of the machine, find out the actual format it outputs, then search for ".NET image library {format}". Profit.

Comment: `raw` means the format of the image is specific to the device that captured it - it isn't going to be encoded with any codec windows has. You'll need to ask the people that made the Xray machine how to re-encode the image.

Comment: Could you post your code where you tried?

Comment: What is the size of the image? How much memory is available to your application? You probably need to solve these problems as well as finding a way to convert the image to a format that you can then display.

Comment: @Simon [GDI+, used by System.Drawing internally, often (incorrectly) throws OutOfMemoryException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771819/system-outofmemoryexception-out-of-memory-gdi).

Comment: I concur with the advise to check the documentation. Medical imaging is often 12-bit per pixel grayscale. That requires special handling.

Comment: Can you post the first 12 bytes of your image? That might help us identify the format of the file.

Comment: Thanks all for help.How to get the bytes??